# How to parse complex string as a data structure

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I need help understanding the easiest way to parse complex string as a Tree data structure.
I'm trying to figure out how could I parse this string using C#.

Here is an example of this string:

```
[[Le[[filet|tartare]]|La grillade]]de gateau|Une [[portion|part]] de gateau
```

[[ ... ]] is a set and | is a separator in set

For example, I would then need to obtain

> ```
>     Set 1
>        Set 1-1
>            Le
>            Set 1-1-1
>               filet
>               tartare
>            La grillade
>     Set 2
>        Une 
>        Set 2-1
>           portion
>           part 
>        de gateau
> ```

Comment: How come `de gateau` comes under set 2, and after `Une ...`?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: @nhahtdh - It is after the second high level separator of the top level set.

Comment: Use a **parser generator** to generate a custom and efficient parser for you! I don't use Windows, so I'm not sure which one to recommend for C#. But there ought to be a dozen around, probably at least one in the standard library. This looks like the typical case for using a L1 parser.

Comment: @Oded: Ah, but there is still a `de gateau` before `Une...` missing from the structure.

Comment: @nhahtdh - True. Guess the OP didn't quite parse the structure correctly ;)

Comment: I edited Set 2 with missing space

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Tree
{
    int currentIndent;

    public Tree(string s)
    {
        this.Trees = new List<Tree>();
        this.Values = new List<string>();
        this.currentIndent = 0;

        if (s == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        if (s == "")
            return;

        int beginPos = 0;
        while (beginPos < s.Length)
        {
            if (s[beginPos] == '[')
            {
                string res = "";
                uint openedBraceCount = 1;
                uint closedBraceCount = 0;
                int index = beginPos + 1;
                while (openedBraceCount != closedBraceCount)
                {
                    if (s[index] == '[')
                        openedBraceCount++;
                    if (s[index] == ']')
                        closedBraceCount++;
                    res += s[index];
                    index++;
                }
                beginPos = index;
                this.Trees.Add(new Tree(res.Substring(0, res.Length - 1)));
            }
            else
            {
                int endPos = beginPos + 1;
                while (endPos < s.Length && s[endPos] != '[')
                    endPos++;
                string[] values = s.Substring(beginPos, endPos - beginPos).Split('|');
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                    values[i] = values[i].Trim();
                this.Values.AddRange(values);
                beginPos = endPos;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Print(TextWriter writer, int indent)
    {
        this.currentIndent = indent;
        Print(writer, 0, this);
        this.currentIndent = 0;
    }

    private void Print(TextWriter writer, int indent, Tree tree)
    {
        foreach (string value in tree.Values)
            writer.WriteLine("{0}{1}", new string(' ', indent), value);
        foreach (Tree t in tree.Trees)
            Print(writer, currentIndent + indent, t);
    }

    public List<Tree> Trees { get; set; }

    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "[[Le[[filet|tartare]]|La grillade]]de gateau|Une [[portion|part]] de gateau";
        var tree = new Tree(s);
        tree.Print(Console.Out, 2);
    }
}
```